# "OR" Restriction on XSD

Tags: xsd

I have a restriction that must be :
4 digits or 0.

the values must be 4 ditits number or the number 0- the answer "refuse to answer".

i know how to make each restriction separatly but not together in the same elemnt.

can you help me ?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression pattern to create your 2 options of 1 digit range 0 or 4 digits and I assume range 0-9 for each since you didn't specify.

```
<xs:element name="foo">
   <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
         <xs:pattern value="[0]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"/>
      </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```